# Is there a way to have my VB.NET program perform some sort of "dying breath" action?

Tags: vb.net, events, exception, error-handling, fatal-error

Is it possible to have some sort of global action/event that triggers in the event of a fatal error? I'd like to be able to have my program write an error file and/or perform other "last breath" (no idea what else to call it...) action if a fatal or unhandled exception occurs that would cause the program to close or crash. Is such a thing possible?

I'm programming in VB.NET v4 using VS2010, if that is important. Also, all users of my app will be authenticated as an administrator (if that matters?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what kind of application you're writing, but these may help:

- [`Application.ApplicationExit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.applicationexit.aspx)
- [`Application.ThreadException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception.aspx)
- [`AppDomain.UnhandledException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx)

Comment: You say it depends on kind of application. Aren't all exceptions bubbled to main `AppDomain` and there they can be handled as "dying breath" regardless of application type?

Comment: @Rafal: Yes, everything can use `AppDomain.UnhandledException` - but for WinForms apps, one of the `Application` events may be better suited.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is [AppDomain.UnhandledException Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx#Y0). And no you do not need any permissions to use it.